# Why sendKeys not typing in value in second iteration

Tags: protractor

We are using protractor to automate testing a create/update workflow of our webapp.

We have a SetValue function which is used in both create and update where this is called to fill in some values before submitting a form.

During the create workflow, this works smooth. However, when the form is opened for update, the clear() works, but sendKeys is not typing in the values.

Any help / inputs in this regard will be very much appreciated.

```
SetValue(value){
    this.elements.$$('input').get(0).clear()
    browser.actions().mouseMove(this.elements).sendKeys(value).perform()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MouseMove will only move the mouse to the specified element, it will not click it therefore your element will never be focused.

Also if you are trying to clear the field before entering the value you should use the same element locator.

Can you try changing that to a click?

```
SetValue(value){
    let field = this.elements.$$('input').get(0)
    field.clear()
    browser.actions().click(field).sendKeys(value).perform()
}
```

Is there a chance that during the create window the element you are sending the keys to is auto focused but is not when the update element is displayed.

Comment: Hi DublinDev, thanks so much :-). Worked fine!  Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

Since Protractor got rid off its control flow some time ago, you could be having issues regarding that?
I would try chaining those promises more accurately perhaps, with `.then()` or using `async/await` and adding a wait on the element before interacting with it:

```
const EC =  protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const yourElement = this.elements.$$('input').get(0);

SetValue = async (value) => {
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(yourElement));
    await yourElement.clear();
    await browser.actions().mouseMove(yourElement).sendKeys(value).perform();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it :-)